# android: can get location with LocationManager with Samsung Galaxy S2 in 30 seconds

Tags: android, locationmanager

I use LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates to request location for both GPS and network provider, and the location settings is selected in "Location and security" settings. But  onLocationChanged is never called in 30 seconds. However, the code works well on other cellphone such as HTC desire. 
But i found there is other app such as Renren can get location in Samsung Galaxy S2.
Could you anyone help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be from china. And your galaxy S2 is sold only in china! we call it (行货). The locationManager can't work well because The google service is removed from the phone.

And. You can query the location directly with your WIFI and Cell-tower.
http://www.google.com/loc/json

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried TelephonyManager.getCellLocation(), but it always crash. Any other way to get location of cell tower?

Comment: You can Collect your Cell-tower infomation and your wifi information.