# Why can't I get the latitude and longitude for my android phone?

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I use the `LocationManager` to get my current location,but I can't,why?
I have already add permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

The following is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mLocation;
public LocationManager locationManager;
private String locationProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
    getLocation();
}

private void getLocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    if (providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        // 如果是GPS
        locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    } else if (providers.contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        // 如果是Network
        locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "没有可用的位置提供器", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    // 获取Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        // 不为空,显示地理位置经纬度
        showLocation(location);
    }else{
        // 监视地理位置变化
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0,mListener);
    }

}

LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    // 如果位置发生变化，重新显示
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        showLocation(location);
    }
};

/** 显示地理位置经度和纬度信息 */
private void showLocation(Location location) {
    String locationStr = "维度：" + location.getLatitude() + "\n" 
            + "经度："+ location.getLongitude();
    mLocation.setText(locationStr);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: What is your compile sdk version?

Comment: I can't get the location, my sdk version 19

Comment: Are you testing in emulator? If not, What is the API device you are trying to get the location? Did you allow Location permissions?

Comment: I testing in my android phone--samsung ,and I have already add three permission,just like I said

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32483251/3940292

Answer (score 0):

In Android 6 and 7 accessing the location is considered a 'dangerous permission' that has to be requested at runtime.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

You can also grant that permission in your system settings (apps > your app > permissions)

Comment: my phone is 5.0.2

Comment: OK, on Android 5 it should work. What exactly is the issue yor're facing? Do you get an error message?

Comment: no error message, I have a textview , I want to get the latitude and longitude and then show at the textview ,but it does't work

Comment: I debug and find the code not go `if (location != null)` it goes to `else`, and into listener,but it didn't run the method `onLocationChanged`,so that ,I need move ?

Comment: Do you get a enabled locationProvider? Which one? Is the locationg service enabled on your device?

Comment: yes, I get the locationprovider is `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`

Comment: It's not unusual that the last known location is null when starting the location service, `onLocationChanged()` should be called as soon your GPS provider gets the location. This may take some time...